# Passing Parameter From Parent to iframe in C#

Tags: c#, iframe, treeview

I have a treeview menu in my Default.aspx page and a set of panels with several controls in Parameters.aspx page. Parameters.aspx is imported to Default in an iframe. Based on the treeNode that the user selects, some panels in Parameters.aspx should either be visible or hidden.eg if the user selects the first node, then panel 4 is hidden but if the user selects second node, all panels are visible.
(I separated them because Parameters.aspx does a postback which results in a new tab opening every time a treeNode is selected).
I have tried 
<
iframe id="iframe" runat="server" src="Parameters.aspx?Param1=<%=treeview_reportName%>" class="noba" scrolling="no">

then calling it with querystring
but I get a variable does not exist error. And when I try passing a session it always returns null when I call it from Parameters.aspx
All code behind is in C#

This is the Default.aspx:

```
    <asp:TreeView ID="treeReport" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
                    ImageSet="Arrows" NodeWrap="True" Width="250px" 
                    LeafNodeStyle-NodeSpacing="2.5px" Font-Names="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"
                    OnSelectedNodeChanged="treeReport_SelectedNodeChanged">
                    <DataBindings>
                        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="ReportTitle" ValueField="Name" 
                            PopulateOnDemand="True" Target="_self"/>
                        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="ChildReport" ValueField="Value" 
                            PopulateOnDemand="True" Target="_self"/>
                        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Reports" ValueField="#Name" Target="_self" />
                    </DataBindings>
                    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
                    <LeafNodeStyle NodeSpacing="2px" />
                    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" 
                        HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                    <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt"/>
                    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" 
                        HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

The treeview codebehind is

```
protected void treeReport_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string treenodeText = treeReport.SelectedNode.Text;
            string treeview_reportName = "summary";
            switch (treenodeText)
            {
                case "Overall incident analysis":
                    treeview_reportName = "overall";
                    break;
                case "All incidents":
                    treeview_reportName = "summary";
                    break;
                default:
                    treeview_reportName = "overall";
                    break;
            }

            Session["ReportGenerate"] = treeview_reportName;
        }
```

And the Parameters.aspx

```
<asp:Panel ID="pn1" runat="server" Width="610px" Visible="true" CssClass="project-content" >
 //Some controls here
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pn2" runat="server" Width="610px" Visible="true" CssClass="project-content" >
 //Some controls here
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pn3" runat="server" Width="610px" Visible="true" CssClass="project-content" >
 //Some controls here
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pn4" runat="server" Width="610px" Visible="true" CssClass="project-content" >
 //Some controls here
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm of the opinion that passing parameters between pages using Session should only be used as a last resort. I think in this case the querystring is a better choice.

One option is to set the src attribute on the iframe control within the SelectedNodeChange postback event. You will need to make sure the iframe control has the runat=server attribute. See the following code:

```
 protected void treeReport_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string treenodeText = treeReport.SelectedNode.Text;
        string treeview_reportName = "summary";
        switch (treenodeText)
        {
            case "Overall incident analysis":
                treeview_reportName = "overall";
                break;
            case "All incidents":
                treeview_reportName = "summary";
                break;
            default:
                treeview_reportName = "overall";
                break;
        }

        iframe.Attributes.Add("src", 
             string.Format("Parameters.aspx?Param1={0}", treeview_reportName));
 }
```

Comment: I tried that but when I try to access the parameter in codebehind of Parameters.aspx like so:
    `
    public static string iframe_report = ""; 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        iframe_report = Request.QueryString["treeview_reportName"];     }`
iframe_report always returns a null value. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think attempting to store the value in a static field is bad form. Instance methods shouldn't change static fields. Why not just reference Request{"treeview_reportName"] where you need it in the code behind?

Comment: I'm still getting a null value

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the treeReport_SelectedNodeChanged event and check the value of Request["treeview_report_Name"]

Comment: Also inspect the Request.Url.PathAndQuery value at the breakpoint

Comment: I did all that and everything within Default.aspx executes are required. The problem happens in Parameters.aspx

Comment: Forgive me, put a breakpoint in Parameters.aspx in the page load event. Check Request["treeview_report_Name"] there. Also do a view source in your browser on default.aspx and verify that the iframe src attribute is set correctly.

Comment: The breakpoint in the page load was the first thing I did actually, always returns null. I even tried calling it from different sections of the code, always null. And the frame attribute is set correctly in the view source

Comment: At this point I'd run Fiddler and verify that the proper URL is being sent to the server for the parameter.aspx page. If that doesn't lead you anywhere, you'll have to post more of your code into your question. For instance, you haven't posted your parameter.aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

in my version i needed to know from witch page i get to Ifarme so i use it like that
inside the page that i go to iframe i have this

```
 <iframe runat="server" id="YourID"  name="YOURname" src="MY_Frame.aspx?source_page=Mypage"></iframe>
```

inside the C# of my Frame i put 
(inside the Page_Load)

```
String SourcePage = Request.QueryString["source_page"].ToString();
```

you get (SourcePage =MYpage)

hope it help you

Answer (score -1):

```
                Mensaje = "Se envio una notificación al Agente: ";
                HtmlControl contentPanel1 = (HtmlControl)this.PnlError.FindControl("Iframe1");
                contentPanel1.Attributes["src"] = "../webMPH/wGeneroEnvio.aspx?lblMensaje=" + Mensaje.Trim()
                                                                           + "&lblUsuario=" + NombreAgente
                                                                           + "&lblMail=" + MailAgente;
```

Comment: Hi Hugo, can you translate your code to English? It's the official language here on Stack Overflow. [Non-English posts might get flagged].(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680).